# How to call the string value to the void function

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

```
[Test]
public void start()
{
    string link = "https://www.w3schools.com/";
    //I want to call this link in below test case
}

[Test]
public void CC1()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    InitialLogin(driver, _wait);
    string url = start(); //here I am calling this function
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); //here I want the above link
}
```

The error message I am getting is

> cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'string'

Comment: Is this specific to a test environment? Since you added a Test Attribute is it about providing testdata to a test?

Comment: yes sir I am learning the automated testing with C# and selenium .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make your start function return the String.

```
public String start(){
  return "https://www.w3schools.com/";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're problem is that you have marked your start method as a test and given it a return type of `void`.

Changing the method as follows would solve your issue:

```
private string start()
{
    //I want to call this link in below test case
    return "https://www.w3schools.com/";
}
```

Better yet would be to use a ```const variable instead of a method to provide the string to your test method (the string is an unchanging constant so a method is not really needed). At the top of the class you could define the link as:

```
private const string StartUrl = "https://www.w3schools.com/"
```

Then in your test use it as follows:

```
[Test]
public void CC1()
{
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    WebDriverWait _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90));
    InitialLogin(driver, _wait);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(StartUrl);//here i want the above link
}
```